# My default database in my django app is on read-only

Tags: django, database, postgresql

On my web app, created with Django, the database 'default' that I am using is on read-only, so I encounter some issue with the admin pages and with the migrate method. The database with the writing access is called with a name because it is not very used compared to the default one.

So my question is what is the best solution between changing the name of my databases or modifying the files of the admin and migrate methods?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to use database routing. During migration specify the name of the database.

```
$ ./manage.py migrate --database=users
```

Please refer - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/